# JSON array transform with JOLT

Tags: jolt

I receive following JSON from some REST API:

```json
{
  "operation_id" : [ 1405494, 1409934, 1420753 ],
  "operation_status" : "success"
}
```

I want to split `operation_id` from array to get 1 by 1 value and create new JSON which should look like:

```json
{
  "operationsStatus": [
    {
      "operation_id": 1405494,
      "operation_status": "success"
    },
    {
      "operation_id": 1409934,
      "operation_status": "success"
    },
    {
      "operation_id": 1420753,
      "operation_status": "success"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I do it with JOLT spec?

Comment: My bad. In `operation_status` should be values from `operation_status` from source JSON. I Fixed expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through the `operation_id` array by using a **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "operation_id": {
          "*": {
            "@": "operationsStatus[&1].&2",
            "@(2,operation_status)": "operationsStatus[&1].operation_status"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the Result of the demo on https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

[image]

Comment: What if I'll have another property like `date`. What will change?

Comment: I figured out myself, thanks!